# An explicit representation of a free nilpotent group by unitriangular matrices

Tags: group-theory, gap, nilpotent-groups

P. Hall proved that every finitely generated torsion-free nilpotent group can be faithfully represented by upper unitriangular matrices over $\mathbb Z$. The most famous example is the integral Heisenberg group, which is free nilpotent, of rank $2$ and class $2$, and is isomorphic to $UT(3,\mathbb{Z})$.

I would like to know what is the *easiest* such representation for the **free nilpotent group** $F(3,2)$, of rank $3$ and class $2$. Its group presentation is
$$F(3,2)=\langle x,y,z \,\|\, [x,[x,y]],[y,[x,y]],[z,[x,y]],[x,[y,z]],[y,[y,z]],[z,[y,z]],[x,[x,z]],[y,[x,z]],[z,[x,z]] \rangle.$$

An algorithm to compute this representation was implemented in GAP, based on the work of de Graaf and Nickel [*de Graaf, Willem A.; Nickel, Werner*, [**Constructing faithful representations of finitely-generated torsion-free nilpotent groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jsco.2001.0497), J. Symb. Comput. 33, No. 1, 31-41 (2002). [ZBL1021.20006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1021.20006).] Unfortunately I am not proficient with GAP to run it myself.

In the above paper the authors state that the algorithm produces a representation for $F(3,2)$ in $UT(6,\mathbb{Z})$.

Is there a faithful representation of $F(3,2)$, over integer matrices, of degree less than $6$?

Comment: It is easy to see that there is no such representation of degree $4$ or less, so that just leaves dimension $5$ as a candidate. I would guess that it cannot be done, but I am not sure!

Comment: Thanks, @DerekHolt! Do you know what does the 6-dimensional representation look like? I.e., what are the images of $x,y,z$ in $UT(6,\mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that I have found an embedding of $F(3,2)$ into ${\rm UT}(5,{\mathbb Z})$. I used a combination of GAP and Magma to do this, but here is the (putative) result in GAP.

The images of the three generators of $F(3,2)$ are

```
a := [
    [ 1, 0, 1, 0, -1 ],
    [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0, -1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
];;
b := [
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 0, -1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
];;
c := [
    [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
    [ 0, 1, 1, 1, -1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 1, 1, -1 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
    [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ]
];;
```

If you calculate the three commutators $[a,b]$, $[a,c]$ and $[b,c]$, you will find that they clearly generate a subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbb Z}^3$, and they are all centralized by $a$,$b$, and $c$, which I think is enough to show that the group they generate is isomorphic to $F(3,2)$.

```
gap> x:=Comm(a,b);; y := Comm(a,c);; z := Comm(b,c);;
gap> Display(x); Display(y); Display(z);
[ [   1,   0,   0,   0,  -1 ],
  [   0,   1,   0,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   1,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   1 ] ]
[ [   1,   0,   0,   1,  -1 ],
  [   0,   1,   0,   0,   1 ],
  [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   1,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,   0,   0,   1 ] ]
[ [  1,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
  [  0,  1,  0,  0,  1 ],
  [  0,  0,  1,  0,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  0,  1,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  0,  0,  1 ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! Since the commutators $x,y,z$ generate a copy of $\mathbb{Z}^3$, which is central in the group, it must indeed be isomorphic to the free nilpotent group of rank 3 (because any non-trivial normal subgroup of a nilpotent group has non-trivial intersection with its centre).

Comment: Can I ask how you found these matrices? Have you simply tested all matrices in $UT(5,\mathbb{Z})$ with entries $\pm 1$?

Comment: I first found the image of the subgroup in ${\rm GL}(5,5)$. So I was looking for a subgroup of order $5^6$ with certain properties in a group of order $5^{10}$, which I did using combinations of thought and  trial and error. I eventually found such a subgroup in which the matrix entries of the three generators were all $0,1$ or $-1$, so it was easy to lift it back to ${\rm GL}(5,{\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: This is an impressive method. It's even more surprising that using a representation of a finite quotient you were able to find a faithful representation of the infinite group. Was there any particular reason why you chose to work with the prime $5$. Have you tried $2$ and $3$ first?

Comment: For primes $2$ and $3$, the finite groups are less generic, and have exponents $8$ and $9$. For $p \ge 5$, the exponent is $p$ (and the group is regular as a $p$-group).

Answer (score 3):

Here is how GAP can be used to construct a 6-dimensional faithful representation of $F(3,2)$.

```
gap> LoadPackage("Polycyclic");;
gap> LoadPackage("nq");;
gap> f:=FreeGroup(3);;
gap> x:=f.1;;y:=f.2;;z:=f.3;;
gap> rels:=[Comm(x,Comm(x,y)),Comm(y,Comm(x,y)),Comm(z,Comm(x,y)),Comm(x,Comm(y,z)),Comm(y,Comm(y,z)),Comm(z,Comm(y,z)),Comm(x,Comm(x,z)),Comm(y,Comm(x,z)),Comm(z,Comm(x,z))];
[ f1^-1*f2^-1*f1^-1*f2*f1*f2^-1*f1*f2, f2^-2*f1^-1*f2*f1*f2*f1^-1*f2^-1*f1*f2, f3^-1*f2^-1*f1^-1*f2*f1*f3*f1^-1*f2^-1*f1*f2, f1^-1*f3^-1*f2^-1*f3*f2*f1*f2^-1*f3^-1*f2*f3, f2^-1*f3^-1*f2^-1*f3*f2*f3^-1*f2*f3, 
f3^-2*f2^-1*f3*f2*f3*f2^-1*f3^-1*f2*f3, f1^-1*f3^-1*f1^-1*f3*f1*f3^-1*f1*f3, f2^-1*f3^-1*f1^-1*f3*f1*f2*f1^-1*f3^-1*f1*f3, f3^-2*f1^-1*f3*f1*f3*f1^-1*f3^-1*f1*f3 ]
gap> G:=f/rels;
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2, f3 ]>
gap> p:=NilpotentQuotient(G);
Pcp-group with orders [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
gap> IsPcpGroup(p);
true
gap> rep:=UnitriangularMatrixRepresentation(p);
[ g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6 ] -> <6 6x6-matrices>
```

Here `NilpotentQuotient` is used just to convert a finitely presented group `G` into a nilpotent group, maybe there is a more straightforward way.
`p` got 6 generators, I guess, they are the original generators and pairwise commutators (it's probably in the docs somewhere). Now one can look at the generators, e.g. the 1st and the 6th:

```
 gap> m:=Image(rep);
 <matrix group of size infinity with 6 generators>
 gap> mg:=GeneratorsOfGroup(m);;
 gap> Display(mg[1]);
 [ [   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0 ],
   [   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0 ],
   [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0 ],
   [   0,   0,  -1,   1,   0,   0 ],
   [   0,   1,   0,   0,   1,   0 ],
   [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   1 ] ]
 gap> Display(mg[6]);
 [ [  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
   [  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0 ],
   [  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0 ],
   [  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0 ],
   [  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0 ],
   [  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1 ] ]
```

For better control, one can use explicit homomorphisms:

```
  gap> F:=FreeGroup(3);
  <free group on the generators [ f1, f2, f3 ]>
  gap> f:=NqEpimorphismNilpotentQuotient(F,2); # this gives F(3,2) as the image
  [ f1, f2, f3 ] -> [ g1, g2, g3 ]
  gap> Image(f);
  Pcp-group with orders [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
  gap> Image(f,F.3*F.1);
  g1*g3*g5
  gap> m:=UnitriangularMatrixRepresentation(Image(f));
  [ g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6 ] -> <6 6x6-matrices>
  gap> Image(m,Image(f,F.1));
  [ [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ] ]
  gap> Display(Image(m,Image(f,F.3*F.1)));
  [ [   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0 ],
    [   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0 ],
    [   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0 ],
    [   0,   0,  -1,   1,   0,   0 ],
    [   0,   1,   0,   0,   1,   0 ],
    [   0,   1,   1,   0,   1,   1 ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful. Is there a command to see what the images of the original 3 generators $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are under this representation? Also, what does the Nilpotent Quotient command actually do? Can you apply this command only to a nilpotent group, or to any group?

Comment: I've added to my answer details on how to actually get matrix images of words in the original generators. Indeed, NilpotentQuotient computes the "biggest", in a naturally defined sense, quotient group (up to a fixed class, 2nd parameter) of an arbitrary f.p. group. More details on the algorithm and the references to theory, see https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/nq/doc/chap0.html

Comment: In `GAP 4.12dev` with `nq 2.5.4` I get error messages at `NilpotentQuotient(G)`, like `The 1st argument is 'fail' which might point to an earlier problem` among other things. Maybe you have encountered such errors in similar cases and know what to do?

Comment: please file a bug report on
https://github.com/gap-packages/nq

Answer (score 1):

The group $F(r,c)$ embeds in the $\mathbf{Q}$-group associated to the free $c$-step nilpotent Lie $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra on $r$ generators.
The latter possesses a natural grading in $\{1,\dots,r\}$.

More generally if a finite-dimensional Lie algebra $g$ over a field $K$ is graded in $\mathbf{Z}$ with $g_0=\{0\}$ [this can be shown to imply $g$ nilpotent], then it has a natural faithful representation in dimension $\dim(g)+1$.

Indeed, first define $D$ as the (invertible) derivation of $g$ acting as $\times k$ on $g_k$. Let $h$ be the semidirect product $K\ltimes g$, where $1\in K$ acts as $D$. Then $h$ has trivial center, so its adjoint representation is faithful, hence is faithful in restriction to $g$. With a little effort and exponentiation one should be able to provide explicit matrices for the corresponding representation of $F(r,c)$.

This is the easiest faithful representation I can figure out, which doesn't mean it's the easiest. And doesn't mean it's the smallest one (indeed for $F(3,2)$ this yields dimension 7, while other answers provide a 5-dimensional one — for $F(r,2)$ it yields dimension $1+r+r(r-1)/2$).

Comment: Thanks, Yves! I was thinking that an explicit faithful representations of $F(3,2)$ in $UT(n,\mathbb{Z})$ must be somewhere in the literature, but I have not found it. The representation discovered by @DerekHolt worked great for me.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan actually it's been done for all nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension $\le 6$ over an arbitrary field of char 0 (or large finite char.) [this specific one is denoted $L_{6,26}$ there]. See N. Rojas, Minimal representations for 6-dimensional
nilpotent Lie algebra, J. Algebra Appl. Vol. 15, No. 10 (2016) 1650191 (19 pages) https://ri.conicet.gov.ar/bitstream/handle/11336/59910/CONICET_Digital_Nro.a86e2a8b-5b9c-4ce1-9c69-8c6dd522e722_A.pdf?sequence=2